# Where's the launching icon in the .minecraft folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had a lot of troubling finding the `.minecraft` folder itself on the computer (windows 8), but now I can't figure out how to launch the game.  I've clicked on pretty much all the folders and icons provided (especially ones with .jar at the end) but so far, no luck.

[image: contents of the .minecraft folder]

Could you help me out?

Comment: It's not going to be in there. You can download the launcher from Minecraft.net (run Minecraft.exe)

Answer (score 3):

You can't run Minecraft using the .jar file as it needs extra starting variables... Which you need the Minecraft launcher to set them up for you. (Login info, version,version-specific libraries, mod-related libraries extra config etc.)

You can download the launcher from http://www.minecraft.net/download